# Rogue sneak attack against Improved Uncanny Dodge

Tags: dnd-3.5e, rogue, barbarian

Can a rogue or assassin, with 6 or 7 total levels, use sneak attack when he is attacking someone with Improved Uncanny Dodge, like a barbarian 5th or Warblade 6th?

1. If rogue attack from invisibilty
2. If rogue flanks target

Comment: Can you explain why you think it should or should not work?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "rogue/assassin 6-7th lvl" – do you mean a multiclassed character with 6 levels of rogue and seven levels of assassin (total of 13 levels)? Or do you mean a rogue/assassin whose total level is 6 or 7? The standard way to write multiclassed characters’ class levels is, for example, “Rogue 6/Assassin 7” (six levels of rogue, seven levels of assassin, thirteen levels total).

Comment: i mean rogue or assasin with total lvl 6 - 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Invisibility: A barbarian of 2nd level and above will keep it's dexterity bonus to AC if attacked by an invisible attacker. That's explicitly stated in his 2nd level feat Uncanny Dodge. There is no way to mitigate this defense through being higher level.

Flanking: A rogue needs to be 4 rogue class levels above the 5th level barbarian with his Improved Uncanny Dodge to be able to flank him effectively.

So a rogue only one or two class levels as rogue above a 5th level barbarian cannot use sneak attack against the barbarian through Invisibility or Flanking alone. The only effective way to use sneak attack would be a means to have the barbarian immobilized prior to the attack, because that would negate his benefits from Uncanny Dodge (cannot dodge if you cannot move). Other options to remove the barbarians bonus to dexterity would include feinting and various grappling situations.

As the Warblade gets Uncanny Dodge at level 2 and Improved Uncanny Dodge at level 6, the same goes for a Warblade of level 6.

Comment: Thanks, i think its true. but our DM is ****ing munchkin =(

Comment: Warblade is in *Tome of Battle* and gets Improved Uncanny Dodge at 6th level. It is also available freely and legally [from Wizards’ website](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ex/20060802a&page=2).

Comment: Oh, cool, didn't know it was free.

Comment: That excerpt lacks the actual maneuvers that the warblade uses, but as luck would have it, you can *also* get all of those from the [maneuver cards](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20061225a) that Wizards published as a web enhancement. You can literally play a warblade, completely free and legal, without ever seeing *Tome of Battle*. Which is wonderful, since it’s one of the best-designed classes in all of 3.5.

Comment: "The only effective way to use sneak attack would be Invisibility *and* a means to have the barbarian immobilized prior to the attack..." Um. I'm not sure what that means. Is that the condition *immobilized* (*RC* 35) or the more casual *immobilized* that comes from being helpless or unconscious? In the first case, the barbarian still isn't vulnerable to sneak attack damage, and, in the second, he'd be vulnerable to sneak attack damage *without* the need for invisibility on the part of the rogue.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I have read the english version of the feat now and it seems that in the original version "immobilized" is enough to lose the dex mod. In my translated PHB, it seemed as if you needed both. I edited that. Anyway, both the SRD and my PHB do not directly reference the "immobilized" condition to any rule or status effect, so I can only leave it a more or less direct quote, even if somewhat unclear.

Comment: Uncanny Dodge does not protect against Feint. I think that a Feint will still make an Uncanny Dodge character lose their Dex bonus, and enable Sneak Attack. Not directly in the question, but a notable exception nonetheless.

Comment: @NeilSlater I added grappling & feints.